# android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustUnspecified|adjustPan" when used on textInputeditext doesn't work

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/inputLayoutEmailId"
            style="@style/TextInputLayoutAppearance1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="74dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            app:errorIconDrawable="@mipmap/ic_error_1"
            app:errorIconTint="@color/red"
            app:errorTextColor="@color/coral"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextInputLayoutHintAppearance"
            app:hintTextColor="@color/text_hint_color"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/etEmailId"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_regular"
                android:hint="@string/email_address"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textColor="@color/color_default"
                android:textColorHint="@color/color_default"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Once focused on above textinput edittext. Its hidden under keyboard.
I have added below line to activity in manifest file but it doesn't work at all
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustUnspecified|adjustPan"

Any Alternative suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the parent of this layout?

Comment: @shafayathossain - CoordinatorLayout is my parent layout

Comment: Can you give full xml?